# How to theme WPF custom controls

Tags: wpf, themes

How I do define and apply themes to my custom control that is hosted in an ElementHost.

VS created Generic.xaml in the Themes folder. If I renamed it to something else (like Blue.xaml), the entire control does not show up.

Another question is what theme xaml files should be set to in VS: Content, Page or Resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always have a Generic.xaml defined.

Copy it, and then change your Blue.xaml to define your "Blue" theme.

Build Action = Page

See as you're hosting your WPF control in a Windows Forms Application with ElementHost, then you might have difficulty in it seeing changes to the theme.

See:

- http://www.actiprosoftware.com/community/thread/20266/how-to-get-themes-working-inside-an-elementho
- [Dynamic Application-level resources are not dynamic when hosted in ElementHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/727141/dynamic-application-level-resources-are-not-dynamic-when-hosted-in-elementhost)